# Should I include a citation every time I refer to the same thing from the same publication?

Tags: publications, citations, writing

In my dissertation, I compare my results to the ABC model presented by John Doe.  It seems excessive to include a reference every time I have a statement such as,

> Compared to ABC, our results show a much larger size distribution.

Unlike the related question, [How do I cite same reference multiple times in a paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55050/21414), in my situation, I am not referencing new information about the model contained in the publication describing the model; I am just referring to the model.  I am inclined to only include a reference the first time I introduce the ABC model. Should I instead include a reference every time I refer to it?

My real issue is that it seems appropriate to include a citation for some of the references but at some point it will become excessive. For example, if I only refer to the DEF model in my introduction and conclusion, but the ABC model 50 times throughout the text, do I only reference each one once, or reference both of them every time.

Comment: @jakebeal, I updated my question to make it clear how it differs from the already answered question.

Comment: While your question is different, I think that the answers may be equally applicable: they all essentially say that you should cite whenever you start talking about the same thing after a significant gap, then give various heuristics about how large a gap is "significant" enough to merit a new citation.

Comment: Most people will not read your dissertation from the first page to the last page. Therefore, it is helpful to refer to the cited result everywhere. It is a matter of convenience for the reader, nothing more.